# Java: Extraneous line getting printed in HTTP get request

Tags: java, http, servlets, get

When I call hit the following GET method from browser, I get an option to download a file containing the actual output and an extraneous line which is something like

Output

```
"Actual output string"

{"h":{"threadLocalInstance":{"threadLocalHashCode":505377872},"immutableThreadLocalInstance":{"threadLocalHashCode":1132005157}}}
```

code

```
@Context
UriInfo info;
@Context
HttpServletRequest request;
@Context
HttpServletResponse response;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("xyz")
public HttpServletResponse pqr() throws IOException {

    ABC abc = new ABC();
    abc.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    String fileName = abc.getFileName();
    //fileName = "results.csv"
    response.setContentType("text/csv");

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

    return response;
}
```

The request and response object are proxies and contain the object corresponding to that extraneous line. Does somebody know how can I remove that line?
(If I do a response.resetBuffer() just before "return response", I get just the extraneous line in the file which suggest that something happens to "response" after getting returned.)

Comment: Till this is resolved, you could return a [ServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponseWrapper.html) repairing all. The cause? A filter?

Comment: @joop could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer suggested by @Joop didn't work for me. So, I am answering in case it doesn't work for you either(but my solution is a bit of hack). What actually was happening is that it was printing toString() of proxy request object. Following is the code/hack which solved atleast my problem :-

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("xyz")
public *String* pqr() throws IOException {

    ABC abc = new ABC();
    abc.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    String fileName = abc.getFileName();
    //fileName = "results.csv"
    response.setContentType("text/csv");

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

    return *""*;
}
```

Comment: Fine. So in effect the output was done twice, by setOutputStream and the annotation handling.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong seems to be the Produces annotation which should be:

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

That concurs with that extra piece of JSON data.

(Maybe better "text/cvs"?)

A minor problem: response headers should be written before the output is written to. Because of response buffering in practice the other way around often works (for small data, when no buffer is written out).

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
String fileName = abc.getFileName();
//fileName = "results.csv"
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
abc.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
```

For testing you could do:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
abc.setOutputStream(baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

// ... dump the bytes
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(data);
out.flush(;
```

Comment: The answer suggested by you didn't work for me. So, I created a workaround for this (and would be answering)